#  Is there a general pattern that could be used to describe Data Migration?

Tags: database, documentation, migration

In our company we have to dismiss a software and introduce a new one. I have received the task to follow and take care of the whole data migration. 
We use 3 different data sources (each containing different kind of information), whose records have to be merged into a unique target DB. Since the new DB has a different schema also some mapping steps are required to coincile data from the two environments.

Technically it is everything clear, but I have to describe in a "proof of concept" the migration process. **About data migration is there a general pattern that could be used to describe it?**

I will describe the involved systems, which data will be moved, the mapping tables used and the planned tests to ensure data quality. However can anyone suggest a different approach? Maybe in this way I can realize that I am missing something in my documentation.

Comment: Take a look at BizTalk and its toolset. I wouldn't necessarily suggest it as a piece of software to perform the migration (too expensive for a 1-off use) but the schema mapping etc. might prove useful.

Comment: Thanks SnOrfus I will have a look at it, surely will help. However I am more interested at the documentation part, something like UML Use Cases and Class Diagram are almost a "must" for the description of the code. I was wondering whether there is something similar also for what concers data migration that is crucial to be included in its documentation.

Comment: Well, IIRC, you can export the schema mapper and orchestration to xps or you can screenshot them at the very least.

Answer (score 2):

Data migration as you describe it is similar to the [Extract, Transform and Load (ETL)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extract,_transform,_load) process; which is mostly used to load operational data into data warehouses, but can be generalized to tackle any data migrations. A number of strategies related to ETL can be found [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Architectural_pattern_%28computer_science%29#Examples).

Comment: Yes, indeed in the specific case it will be more like an ETL process. I was interested on the "documentation" perspective, if possible in a general way. However +1 for the links!